# How to output calculation to 4 decimal places

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in SQL Workbench and want my output to include 4 decimal places. I have tried different combinations of casting 'sessions', 'transactions', and 'cvr' as DECIMAL as well as using ROUND, and I can't seem to get the output I'm looking for. 'sessions' and 'transactions' are both in NUMERIC(19,2) format.

Ideally, I want to stay away from casting to float to avoid losing precision.

```
select cast((transactions/sessions) as decimal(10,5)) as cvr
from(select name
      ,sum(cast(sessions as decimal(10,5))) as sessions
      ,sum(cast(transactions as decimal(10,5))) as transactions
```

Comment: the sql code you provided is not a valid sql code , please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Replaced tags based on "sql workbench" statement in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get output with 4 decimal places

```
SELECT FORMAT(123.456789, 4) as col
```

> 123.4567

---

```
SELECT FORMAT(123.456, 4) as col
```

> 123.4560